# How to add HEX-Data into Registry with Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup

I was wondering what I have to write when I want to add HEX-Data into registry?

I have

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\FOOBAR]
"Type"=dword:00000110
"ImagePath"=hex(2):43,00,3a,00,5c,00,73,00,64,00,69,00,62,00,61,00,73,00,65,00,\
 5c,00,64,00,62,00,6e,00,74,00,35,00,73,00,76,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,00,\
 00
```

and I want to add this by my Inno-Script to the registry.

The first value is easy...

```
Root: "HKLM"; Subkey: "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\FOOBAR"; ValueType: dword; ValueName: "Type"; ValueData: "00000110"
```

but what is about the hex part? I could not finde some like `HEX` instead of `DWORD` does this means I have to do some converts if I have data like this ?

and I have a second value that is similar but actually it seams to be different since there is `hex:...` and not `hex(2):...`

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Centura SQLBase\Security]
"Security"=hex:01,00,14,80,b8,00,00,00,c4,00,00,00,14,00,00,00,30,00,00,00,02,\
 00,1c,00,01,00,00,00,02,80,14,00,ff,01,0f,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,\
 00,00,02,00,88,00,06,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,fd,01,02,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,\
 05,12,00,00,00,00,00,18,00,ff,01,0f,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,\
 20,02,00,00,00,00,14,00,8d,01,02,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,04,00,00,00,00,\
 00,14,00,8d,01,02,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,06,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,00,01,\
 00,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,0b,00,00,00,00,00,18,00,ff,01,0f,00,01,02,00,\
 00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,25,02,00,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,12,00,00,00,\
 01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,12,00,00,00
```

Comment: What you see is a hexadecimal representation of a Unicode string stored in the `REG_EXPAND_SZ` data type key. Use the `expandsz` value type for that entry. And write that entry value as string. After recoding your data I got `C:\sdibase\dbnt5sv.exe`. But you can simply import this registry export into your registry and grab the values from regedit (as well as you will see the data types there). Except that you will need to fix the value of your first entry.

Comment: @TLama that's right... so you say I can simply use the expandsz and add the value as string ? like `ValueType: expandsz; ValueName: "ImagePath"; ValueData: "c:\newpath\dbnt5sv.exe"` If yes, add a answere,  I will accept it of course :)

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant to say. Except that fix your first entry. It's not decimal but hexadecimal value, so you need to write it as `$00000110`. Here is [`some reading about the *.reg files`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727154.aspx). Still, it's much easier to import the file and get the values from regedit, I'd say.

Comment: I know it's easier to do it with a .reg but I feel better if have the option to configure the input data before instead of packing x reg files in my installer :)

Comment: No, I mean that you could import them into a dedicated machine and see (copy) the data types and values in regedit. There you would see e.g. that the type is `REG_EXPAND_SZ` and you would be able to copy the string as well.

Comment: Oh ok, I allready did that and it worked fine. But how do I do this with real hex like the "security" part? ( REG_BINARY )

Comment: You can find that the type is `REG_BINARY` (`binary` in your entry). For this type Inno Setup help for the `ValueData` parameter says, *if the data type is binary, this is a sequence of hexadecimal bytes in the form: "00 ff 12 34".* Which means that you just need to replace commas with spaces because that value is already a hexa byte series. And of course you will need to remove the *.reg file line break backslashes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `hex` entry maps to the `REG_BINARY` value type, and `hex(2)` to the `REG_EXPAND_SZ` type in the *.reg files. Here is the table that shows the *.reg file entry to registry data type mapping ([`source`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727154.aspx)):

```
┌─────────────┬────────────────┐
│ File entry  │ Registry type  │
├─────────────┼────────────────┤
│ hex         │ REG_BINARY     │
├─────────────┼────────────────┤
│ dword       │ REG_DWORD      │
├─────────────┼────────────────┤
│ hex(2)      │ REG_EXPAND_SZ  │
├─────────────┼────────────────┤
│ hex(7)      │ REG_MULTI_SZ   │
├─────────────┼────────────────┤
│ none        │ REG_SZ         │
└─────────────┴────────────────┘
```

So, the export from your question represents a comma separated series of `REG_BINARY` type data in hexadecimal byte notation, which you can write as a `binary` value type entry with space separated series of bytes in hexadecimal notation. In other words, you'll just replace commas by spaces in that series (and strip out `\` linebreaks of course).

I will shorten up your example a bit, let's take this as an input:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Centura SQLBase\Security]
"Security"=hex:01,00,14,80,b8,00,00
```

This is how the Inno Setup entry can be written:

```
[Registry]
Root: "HKLM"; Subkey: "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Centura SQLBase\Security"; \
  ValueType: binary; ValueName: "Security"; ValueData: "01 00 14 80 b8 00 00"
```